# PHP - checking isset on a $_SESSION[$_REQUEST[]] variable

Tags: php

Seems an easy one, but cannot work out why:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION[$_REQUEST["form_id"]]))
{
     //do stuff
}
```

reutrns

```
Notice: Undefined index: form_id
```

`empty` returns same response.

This has been driving me mad for a while. :)

Comment: You need to make sure form_id is passed as GET or POST variable. It's not the $_SESSION index where the error originates from.

Comment: `var_dump($_REQUEST)`, also, I'd prefer using `$_GET` or `$_POST` instead

Comment: `$_COOKIE`, `$_ENV`, `$_FILES`, `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_REQUEST`, `$_SERVER`, `$_SESSION` are all seperate global arrays. You may need to switch the inners of `$_REQUEST` ('form_id') into the `$_SESSION` manually. `$_SESSION['form_id'] = $_REQUEST['form_id']` (off course with the isset and custom checks you need).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling isset for `$_SESSION` but as the error states the issue is with `$_REQUEST['form_id']` not being set.

```
 if (!isset($_REQUEST['form_id']) || !isset($_SESSION[$_REQUEST['form_id']])) {
```

Comment: your boolean logic needs addressing. if REQUEST is NOT set =TRUE - because you use && (AND) move to next section, as both need to equate to TRUE, now we get undefined index again

Comment: ! preceeds && so if request is not set it will stop there no? http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: NO !isset($_REQUEST['form_id']) is `TRUE` (in the above scenario) then because of && (left) it will move to the next statement. If it was `FALSE` then it would stop there. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws ( TRUE && TRUE) -> (!TRUE || !TRUE)

Comment: Oh my bad I see what you're saying. It should be || instead of && /edited

Answer (score 2):

That's because it resolves `$_REQUEST['form_id']` first and that causes the notice. You could do this instead:

```
if (!isset($_REQUEST['form_id']) || !isset($_SESSION[$_REQUEST["form_id"]]))
{
     //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please check if key exists with

```
 array_key_exists('form_id', $_REQUEST);
```

before checking value with

```
isset($_REQUEST['form_id']);
```

Answer (score -1):

or check if your params are empty like

```
<?php 
if (!empty($_REQUEST['form_id'])) {
  // do anything
}
else
{
  // I can't find the key in array 
}
?>
```